# How can I determine the type returned by eval on proto expression?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, metaprogramming, boost-proto

I defined a context for my grammar which is templated on the input types, something like the snippet below. I am missing the types where the ???? are.

Before I start writing recursive templates to figure them out, is there anything in proto already?

```
template<typename PlaceholderTypes>  // mpl vector of placeholder types
class calculator_context
    : public proto::callable_context< calculator_context<PlaceholderTypes>, proto::null_context const >
{
public:

    template<typename T>
    struct MakePtrType
    {  
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<T> type;
    };

    // Values to replace the placeholders
    typedef typename boost::mpl::transform<PlaceholderTypes,MakePtrType<boost::mpl::_1> >::type inputTypes;    
    typename boost::fusion::result_of::as_vector<typename inputTypes::type>::type args;

    // Handle the placeholders:
    template<int I>
    typename boost::shared_ptr<boost::mpl::at<PlaceholderTypes,boost::mpl::int_<I> > >::type operator()(proto::tag::terminal, placeholder<I>)         
    {
        typedef typename boost::mpl::at<PlaceholderTypes,boost::mpl::int_<I> >::type param_type;

        boost::shared_ptr<param_type> p = boost::fusion::at_c<I>(this->args);
        return p;        
    }

    // Define the result type of the calculator.
    // (This makes the calculator_context "callable".)        
    typedef ??????? result_type;        

    template <typename Expr1, typename Expr2>
    result_type operator()(proto::tag::plus, const Expr1& lhs, const Expr2& rhs) 
    {        
        typedef ??? lhs_result_type; // result of proto::eval(lhs, ctx);                
        .... 
    }    
};
```

Comment: According to [the reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/proto/reference.html#header.boost.proto.eval_hpp), the return type of `proto::eval()` is `proto::result_of::eval<Expr, Context>::type`, so the `lhs_result_type` typedef should be something like `typedef typename proto::result_of::eval<Expr1, calculator_context>::type lhs_result_type;`. As to your overall `result_type`, I'm not sure --  isn't that up to you as the context author? I'm assuming it should be the `common_type<>` of your input types...